# Why are documents not being deleted from the mongodb database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to delete a document form the mongodb database but it isn't working. I don't understand why because the console doesn't give any errors and displays the query object properly. However, when I view the database the respective document is still there.

**URL**
    `http://localhost:7000/delete/5c641f44923cf17c1cfe1002`

**Console**

```
{ _id: '5c641f44923cf17c1cfe1002' }
1 document deleted
```

**Server.js:**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;



app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
// Connection URL
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/DataBaseName";

app.listen(7000);

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// Express routes

//Default routes
app.get('/', function(req, res){

    MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db("DataBaseName");
        dbo.collection("customers").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(db);
            db.close();
            res.render('index', {result:result});
        });
    });
});
//Submit button route
app.post('/submitData',urlencodedParser,function(req, res){

    MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, db) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var dbo = db.db("DataBaseName");
      dbo.collection("customers").insertOne(req.body, function(err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("1 document inserted");
        db.close();
      });
    });
    res.redirect("/");
});


// var _mongodb = require('mongodb');
//  var ObjectId = mongodb.ObjectId;

app.get('/delete/:id', function (req, res) {
    MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, db) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var dbo = db.db("DataBaseName");
      dbo.collection("customers").deleteOne({_id: new ObjectId(req.params.id) }, function(err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
        // console.log({_id: req.params.id});
        console.log("1 document deleted");
        db.close();
      });
    });
res.redirect("/");
});

// Catch all other routes
app.get('*',function(req, res){
    res.send("You lost Niqqa!");
});
```

**An entry in the database**
This is what it looks like in mongodb compass community.

```
_id:ObjectId("5c641f44923cf17c1cfe1002")
name:"Please delete me"
priority:"high"
```

Comment: Could you paste the document you're trying to delete ?

Comment: Paste the documents? do you mean paste the documents structure as in the way it looks like in the database?

Comment: Yes, just the one with _id: 5c641f44923cf17c1cfe1002

Comment: I updated the question to include an entry.

Comment: Could be `deleteOne({_id: ObjectId(req.params.id) } ...)`

Comment: @Ananth I thought that was just the way compass displayed it. It didn't work though. I got the following error `ReferenceError: ObjectId is not defined`

Comment: @Simple you need to import ObjectId as well, like `const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;`, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should convert the id from the request to ObjectId as it's passed now as string which won't match the document.

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
const ObjectId = mongodb.ObjectId;

app.get('/delete/:id', function (req, res) {
    MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, db) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var dbo = db.db("DataBaseName");
      dbo.collection("customers").deleteOne({_id: new ObjectId(req.params.id) }, function(err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log({_id: req.params.id});
        console.log("1 document deleted");
        db.close();
      });
    });
res.redirect("/");
```

You can also check the res from the delete operation to know whether any documents where deleted or not. The res should have `deletedCount` based on [mongodb node driver docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Collection.html#~deleteWriteOpResult).

Comment: I got the following error`import mongodb from 'mongodb';
       ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Comment: Can you explain the first two lines of code please?

Comment: you can try it like this
```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var MongoClient = mongodb. MongoClient;
var ObjectId = mongodb.ObjectId;
```

Comment: I replaced the first two lines you provided with this but it still gives errors

Comment: The first error is that MongoClient is already declared. Removing this gives the error  mongodb is not defined

Comment: how do you require mongodb? can you share more of your code?

Comment: I updated the question to show the entire server.js file.

Comment: It's working now thank you. Can you tell me what you changed though. It seems as though all you changed was var to const.

Comment: `const mongodb = require('mongodb');` this line was why you were getting mongodb is not defined. previously you were not saving the mongodb object in a variable when you required it to get `MongoClient`. so I broke it down to requiring mongodb and save it in a const then use it to get `MongoClient` and `ObjectId`.